# Lithium: New command don't work

Tags: php, cakephp, lithium

I've acted in accordance with this guid [Link](http://li3.me/docs/manual/common-tasks/console-applications.md).

Then, I created `Repos.php` file in `/app/extensions/command/` And run `li3` in command line but do not see the following message:

```
COMMANDS via app
repos
```

I see the following text only:

```
    Lithium console started in the development environment. Use the --env=environment key to alter this.
COMMANDS via lithium
    create
    The `create` command allows you to rapidly develop your models, views, controllers, and tests
    by generating the minimum code necessary to test and run your application.

    g11n
    The `G11n` set of commands deals with the extraction and merging of message templates.

    help
    Get information about a particular class including methods, properties,
    and descriptions.

    route
    The route command lets you inspect your routes and issue requests against the router.

    test
    Runs a given set of tests and outputs the results.

See `li3 help COMMAND` for more information on a specific command.
```

**Have I done something wrong?**

Comment: What path are you running this from?

Comment: @NateAbele This path `/app/extensions/command/`

Comment: Try it from the `app` directory.

Comment: @NateAbele Thank you, but this solution is not helpful